# Which open source charts support and load in IE8

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, charts

We are developing a page using html5,bootstrap where charts has to be loaded. We used D3.js. But in IE8 its not loading. We have to use only open source plugin not licensed. Please suggest any open source chart plugin which load in IE8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Highcharts is free for non-commercial use. Its running here on a bootstrap site I just tested it in IE8 and it works fine.

Questions regarding Product or service recommendations might get closed FYI